# Click events on a container?

Tags: javascript

Is possible to intercept click events on a container, independently from what is inside? (say a picture, a flash animation and such).

I would like to set a specific area inside a container, to receive click events, so I can execute an action.
Is this possible in JS? If not, what should I use?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Add an event listener to the container, and figure out the mouse coordinates in relation to the container's position if you want to only affect a particular area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope, it would be work for you

```
<div id="container">
   <span>Click span</span>
   <b>Click b</b>
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("container").onclick = function(Event){
       console.log(this, Event.target);
    }
</script>
```

`this` provides attached event `element`;

`Event.target` provides inside `element` of attached event;

Comment: @newbiez So in the end, you didn't need a click handler for a portion of the container, right?

Comment: @Artjom: Yes I do; I am experimenting and this works fine with one div. Altho if you have them nested; problems arise. Experimenting for a solution; altho my initial question was answered

Comment: @newbiez But then it's not fully answerer and you don't need to accept it yet.